# Indexing ndarray by ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have a first ndarray, foo, in which I want to select several elements.

```
foo = array([0, 10, 30] , [20, 40, 60], [30, 50, 70])
```

To be precised, I have another ndarray, bar, in which I store the rows I want in each column of my first ndarray.

```
bar = array([1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1])
```

What I want as result is :

```
array([20, 50, 30] , [0, 10, 60])
```

Is it a vectorized way to do it ?

When I try foo[bar], it increases the size of the array.
That is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [17]: foo[bar, np.arange(3)]
Out[17]: 
array([[20, 50, 30],
       [ 0, 10, 60]])
```

---

The 1-dimensional array `np.arange(3)` is broadcasted to the same shape as `bar`
so that it is equivalent to

```
In [35]: X, Y = np.broadcast_arrays(bar, np.arange(3)); Y
Out[35]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

`X` is the same as `bar` since broadcasting does not change the shape of `bar`.

Then [NumPy integer array indexing rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) say that the `(i,j)` element of `foo[X, Y]` equals

```
foo[X, Y][i, j] = foo[X[i,j], Y[i,j]]
```

So for example,

```
foo[bar, np.arange(3)][0, 1] = foo[ bar[0,1],  Y[0,1] ]
                             = foo[2, 1]
                             = 50
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! It worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

you need to also specify the columns to go with each index, respectively.

try this:

```py
import numpy as np

foo = np.array([[0, 10, 30], [20, 40, 60], [30, 50, 70]])
bar = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

foo[bar, range(len(foo))]
```

Output:

```py
array([[20, 50, 30],
       [ 0, 10, 60]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much